# how to overwrite existing table from another database

Tags: sql

I have tried many times but i could not find the proper answer again i am asking same questing,

1 query

```
 select * From acct_db2016.dbo.acct_tran where trc_acno='12008001'
```

if i search like this i am getting 10 rows,

2 query

```
  select * From acct_db.dbo.acct_tran where trc_acno='12008001'
```

i am getting 4 rows
 so i want to insert value to  (1st query) data base from (2nd query )data base
so the answer rows will be 10+4=14 rows(what i meant is overwrite 1 query database)

Comment: Please add a tag to show what database product you are using.  The syntax for working across databases (and the ability to do so) vary by product.

Comment: are you trying to add the rows from database 2 to database 1?  if so, there is no need to "overwrite".  just insert the records from database 2.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Do you want to copy rows from one table to the other table? Or do you just want to read the rows from two tables?

Comment: i want join both the tables and insert TO 1ST DATABASE

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question properly and am correct in assuming the schema for the 2 tables is identical, then what you want is a UNION.

```
select * From acct_db2016.dbo.acct_tran where trc_acno='12008001'
UNION
select * From acct_db.dbo.acct_tran where trc_acno='12008001'
```

To insert the results from the second query into the first table you should use something like:

```
INSERT INTO acct_db2016.dbo.acct_tran select * From acct_db.dbo.acct_tran where trc_acno='12008001'
```

The syntax for this may vary depending on what database you're using. This link should give you more details on the generic SQL implementation. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: UNION ALL is probably what OP wants.

Comment: i am getting the answer, but i want insert it to 1st database